# Error dropping primary key constraint in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I started using YugabyteDB for micro services development. Part of the migration, I started using YugaByteDB to a Keycloak installation.

During keycloak installation, I noticed the following error related to liquibase changeset from Keycloak:

```
Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: dropping a primary key constraint is not yet supported [Failed SQL: (0) ALTER TABLE public.USER_REQUIRED_ACTION DROP CONSTRAINT CONSTRAINT_2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your version, YugabyteDB prevents from dropping primary keys. This is what causes the issue. It’s been reported on https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/issues/8735 and it’s currently committed in https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/commit/6c9d8e8f122931571dffb9f6bd0c9e806b79a39a. You need to upgrade to a release that includes that commit.